# How to fix 'tuple' object has no attribute 'open'?

Tags: python, google-sheets, pydrive

Im parsing data for study purposes so I create scraping module, data frame module and now I need to finish "upload to Google Drive data frame as Google Sheet" but stuck on this error.

```
from fileinput import filename
import gspread

credentials = {...
}
gc = gspread.oauth_from_dict(credentials)

tag = bs_search
sh = gc.open(filename, 'kid')
worksheet = sh.add_worksheet(title = tag, rows=100, cols=20)
worksheet.update([df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist())
worksheet.update_cell(1, 4, 'Send to')
worksheet.update_cell(1, 5, 'Not Send to')
worksheet.update_cell(1, 6, 'Instagram')
```

Output:

```
   13 gc = gspread.oauth_from_dict(credentials)
     15 tag = bs_search
---> 16 sh = gc.open(filename, 'kid')
     17 worksheet = sh.add_worksheet(title = tag, rows=100, cols=20)
     18 worksheet.update([df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist())

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'open'
```

Comment: See the [docs here](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-end-users-using-oauth-client-id) with example code showing a tuple returned by the function: `gc, authorized_user = gspread.oauth_from_dict(credentials)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs for the gspread project, they have an example for this function:

```
gc, authorized_user = gspread.oauth_from_dict(credentials)
```

Notice there are two values before the equals.

More information: https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html

Comment: Look like I just forget to add ```authorised_user``` 

Going to check right now!

Comment: Can I ask you for a tip how to download ```authorised_user``` from Google Dev Console? I simply don't see it 

(Previosly I downloaded client_secrets.json and it work ok but sorry I really can't understand where is ```authorised_user``` because on my Oauth screen are only credentials... )